# Odd maps from $S^1$ to $S^1$ viewed from the quotient $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ perspective

Tags: algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

Reading a proof about degree oddity of odd continuous maps from   $S^1$ to $S^1$, I have the following:

Let $f : S^1 → S^1$ be an odd map :

$\forall z ∈ S^1 ⊂ \mathbb{C}, f (−z) = −f (z)$        $\textbf{(**)}$

If we look at $S^1 \cong \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, $\textbf{(**)}$ would tranlate to $ f ([x + 1/2 ]) = f ([x]) + [ 1/2 ]$.

Could you please help me understand this new expression?

Thanks!

Comment: Think about $e^{2\pi i x}: \Bbb R \to S^1$. This factors through $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$, providing the usual identification to $S^1$.

Comment: Thanks, in $S^1$ if $z=e^{2i\pi x}$, we have $-z=e^{2i\pi x}e^{i\pi}$ hence the $1/2$ factor... trying to dig more